# R: installing RMySQL package failed

Tags: mysql, r, installation

I am trying to install `RMySQL` package in R, by `install.packages("RMySQL")`, but it complains that it couldn't find the include libraries.

```
Configuration error:
 could not find the MySQL installation include and/or library
 directories.  Manually specify the location of the MySQL
 libraries and the header files and re-run R CMD INSTALL.
```

So, then I installed `mysql` in Ubuntu as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

This installation worked fine, but still I get the same error in R. Can someone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: have you installed `RMySQL` dependencies (`DBI`)?

Comment: I did after reading your comment, but still I have the same issue, and can't install RMySQL.

Comment: `dpkg -l|grep libmysqlclient` what outputs?

Comment: The output is two lines:

Comment: ii  libmysqlclient18                            5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                 MySQL database client library

Comment: ii  libmysqlclient18:i386                       5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                 MySQL database client library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked this

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-cran-rmysql

so you should have `r-cran-rmysql` package inside your Ubuntu packages list. Therefore

- from inside `R` remove `DBI`, `RMySQL` packages,
- then    `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rmysql`

HTH